# Python analogue to Tomcat and another Servlet-containers

Tags: python, django, packaging

Is there any way to deploy Django (or another WSGI framework) app simply by putting egg package to relevant directory, like Tomcat for WAR packages does?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Jython` (a Java-based Python interpreter) and actually [deploy a Django app as a war file with Tomcat](http://pythonhosted.org/django-jython/war-deployment.html)!

It's quite outdated though, and [`gunicorn`](http://gunicorn.org/) makes it trivial enough to deploy an app that it's not much different.